# How can I decrypt 8 times repeated 128-bit AES key encrypted by 1024-bit RSA?

Tags: rsa

There is a 128-bit AES key $m$, and it's encrypted by 1024-bit RSA modulus $n$ as $$c = (m\mathbin\| m\mathbin\|\ldots\mathbin\|m)^e \bmod n.$$

There are eight $m$ in $m\mathbin\| m\mathbin\|\ldots\mathbin\|m$.

Is there any way to find a message $m$?

The key is repeated 8 times, but I can't utilize this information to decrypt.

Comment: Is this a homework question? What is the source of this question?

Comment: If $e$ is small (such as $3$), then it is to possible to recover $m$ easily, but this information is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no proper padding and the message $m$ can be recovered easily if $e$ is small.

First, we can rewrite $(m\mathbin\| m\mathbin\|\ldots\mathbin\|m)$ as 
$$
(m + m2^{128} + \cdots + m2^{128\times 7}) = m(1 + 2^{128} + \cdots + 2^{128\times 7}),
$$
and when we put it back in the equation, we have
$$
c = m^e(1 + 2^{128} + \cdots + 2^{128\times 7})^e \mod n.
$$
We can compute
$$
c' = c\times (1 + 2^{128} + \cdots + 2^{128\times 7})^{-e} \mod n,
$$
so we have the relation $c' \equiv m^e \bmod n$. In the case that $m^e < n$ (which happens for $e=3$, $5$ or $7$), then this is in fact an equality:
$$
c' = m^e.
$$
The value $m$ can be recovered by taking the $e$-nth root of $c'$.

Comment: Yes. That works for $e\in\{3,5,7\}$.

Comment: When you compute $c'$, it should be $c'=c\times(1+...)^{-e}$ to get $c' \equiv m^e \bmod n$, not $c'=c\times(1+...)^{-1}$. I can't edit a single character, and don't want to modify the rest of your answer ;-)

Comment: @Faulst Thanks!